# What is the best way to share contacts over the Internet to two company locations (without using exchange)

Tags: cloud, contacts

I am working with a small law firm that has two locations... one in Chicago and one in Dallas. Everyone is using Macs and there is no way to incorporate MS Exchange into their current setup (they don't want to pay for it).

I am trying to figure out a way to have a list of contacts that can be updated by any user in either location and accessed from anywhere. I want something along the lines of Google calendar but for contacts.

The perfect solution for me would be something along the lines of sharing google apps contacts, but from what I understand, that is not possible without using an API. I am fairly proficient with computers in general, but not programming.

How can I have a centralized group of contact information that can be accessed and updated by multiple users in multiple locations using the Internet?

I have been messing around with this forever. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dropbox > notepad. If you want to get really fancy, you can use Excel

Answer (score 2):

Google app for your own domain

https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Funambol](http://www.funambol.com/). It's mainly for mobiles but it has plugins for different clients like Thunderbird and Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party. Funambol would indeed be an option. Alternatively, you could set up an LDAP server (such as OpenLDAP) to share the address book. Because Thunderbird does not support editing the LDAP contacts, you could use a third party program for that (see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sharing_address_books#LDAP)